# How to query on subset of composite primary key?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Pk id;

    public Pk getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Pk id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}

@Embeddable
public class Pk implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3090221844117493661L;
    private Integer type;
    private String userId;

    public Pk() {
    }

    public Pk(String userId, Integer type) {
        this.setUserId(userId);
        this.setType(type);
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    // Auto-generated by Eclipse.
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((type == null) ? 0 : type.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((userId == null) ? 0 : userId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    // Auto-generated by Eclipse.
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Pk other = (Pk) obj;
        if (type != other.type)
            return false;
        if (userId == null) {
            if (other.userId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!userId.equals(other.userId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}

public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Pk> {

    List<MyEntity> findAllByUserId(String userId);

}
```

When I initialize Spring Data JPA I am getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myEntityRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property user found for type MyEntity!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:615)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)
    at com.myproject.backend.common.ServiceContext.start(ServiceContext.java:293)
    at com.myproject.run(AbstractServiceContainer.java:55)
    at com.myproject..run(AbstractServiceContainer.java:1)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:42)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:76)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:72)
    at com.myproject..main(CombinedServiceContainer.java:106)
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property user found for type MyEntity!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:213)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:321)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:301)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:60)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:168)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:320)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:169)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 18 more
```

Question: **Does Spring Data JPA not support querying on a subset of a primary key?** Or will I need to implement a custom repository method for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I also tried doing this with `@IdClass` instead:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@IdClass(Pk.class)
public class MyEntity {
    @Id private Integer type;
    @Id private String userId;

    public Pk getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Pk id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}

@IdClass(Pk.class)
public class Pk implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3090221844117493661L;
    private Integer type;
    private String userId;

    public Pk() {
    }

    public Pk(String userId, Integer type) {
        this.setUserId(userId);
        this.setType(type);
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    // Auto-generated by Eclipse.
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((type == null) ? 0 : type.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((userId == null) ? 0 : userId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    // Auto-generated by Eclipse.
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Pk other = (Pk) obj;
        if (type != other.type)
            return false;
        if (userId == null) {
            if (other.userId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!userId.equals(other.userId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

This did gave me a different error message, a `NullPointerException`, that was hinting to me that Spring Data JPA was unable to build the query for `findAllByUserId(...)`. I made a custom implementation of that query method instead:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Pk>, MyEntityRepositoryCustom {

}

public interface MyEntityRepositoryCustom {

    List<MyEntity> findAllByUserId(String userId);

}

public class MyEntityRepositoryImpl implements MyEntityRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<MyEntityRepositoryCustom> findAllByUserId(String userId) {
        return em
                .createQuery("select o from MyEntity o where o.userId=:userId",
                        MyEntity.class).setParameter("userId", userId).getResultList();
    }

}
```

...and voilá, **it works!**

Answer (score 24):

You need to tell JPA where to look for the userId field (in the embedded id, that is).
If you change the name of the repository method to `findAllByIdUserId`, it should work.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you post your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711695/how-to-query-on-a-subset-of-composite-primary-key-with-embeddedid-or-id-key-ob) I will accept it.

Comment: @StefanDeitmer see my version this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46711695/2084253

Comment: I'm dealing with a composite primary key with 3 parts; Spring JPA nicely generated an implementation for me (the embedded ID in the entity is called `key`; notice that it appears twice in the method name): 
    `List<Thing> findAllByKeyFileDateAndKeyFormNumber(LocalDate fileDate, int formNumber);`