# Spring JPA - Find By EmbeddedId partially

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Below code is for demo purpose only.

My *Entity* bean looks like this

```
@Entity
class Employee {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeKey employeeKey;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // Other fields
    // Getter and Setters
}
```

The *Embeddable* class:

```
@Embeddable
class EmployeeKey implements Serializable {

    private int employeeId;
    private String branchName;
    private String departmentName;

    //Getter and Setters
}
```

---

I can write *JPARepository* interface method to find Employees by the EmbeddedId that returns me results as well.

```
interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, EmployeeKey> {
        List<Employee> findByEmployeeKey(EmployeeKey employeeKey);
}
```

---

**Question:**
Suppose, while querying I have *employeeId* and *branchName* only, and I don't want to put filter on *departmentName*

- In such cases how can I write my Repository method
- Does JPA have something in-build for such scenario?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020699/how-to-query-on-subset-of-composite-primary-key

Comment: @Zeromus Thanks for the link. However, I am not in favour of writing repository implementation. I am wondering if I can make use of built-in functionality to address the question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is how it worked for me.

@Ketrox's answer is absolutely correct and works fine. But in my real scenario I had 6 fields to search by and which resulted in an 120+ characters long method name. (*Something like below*)

```
List<Employee> findByEmployeeKeyField1AndEmployeeKeyField2AndEmployeeKeyField3AndEmployeeKeyField4AndEmployeeKeyField5AndEmployeeKeyField6(String field1, String field2, String field3, String field4, String field5, String field6);
```

Which is certainly not good enough to read and more than good enough to make [codenarc](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/) unhappy.

---

Finally I used find by example and that turned out to be really pleasant solution.

***Repository:***

```
//skipped lines    
import org.springframework.data.domain.Example
//skipped lines
interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, EmployeeKey>{
    List<Employee> findAll(Example<Employee> employee);
}
```

***Usage:***

```
// Prepare Employee key with all available search by keys (6 in my case)
EmplyeeKey key = new EmplyeeKey();
key.setField1("field1_value");
key.setField2("field2_value");
//Setting remaining 4 fields

// Create new Employee ans set the search key
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setEmployeeKey(key);


// Call the findAll by passing an Example of above Employee object
List<Employee> result = employeeRepository.findAll(Example.of(employee));
```

I have elaborated the search by [Spring Data JPA find by @EmbeddedId Partially](http://www.amitph.com/spring-data-jpa-embeddedid-partially/)

Answer (score 32):

```
List<Employee> findByEmployeeKeyEmployeeIdAndEmployeeKeyBranchName(
        int employId,
        String branchName);
```

Should work [Have a look at query derivation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will give it a try and let you know if that works for me

Comment: You answer is correct. It works. But for my scenario where I have 6 search by fields the method name grows like hell. I then found and used another solution which I have posted as an answer here.