# Fetching Data through Hibernate without passing Primary Key

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql

I am using a composite primary key which is defined in Entity Class as :

```
@EmbeddedId
private ParticipantPrimaryKey pKey;
```

and the primary Key consists of Event Id and Student Id which are defined in PrimaryKey Entity Class.

Now i need to fetch the participants from the table which are participating in any particular Event.

The HQL query that is not working due to above problem:

```
select pe from ParticipantEntity pe where pe.eventId=?
```

If i use any other field then it'll work as they are present in the Entity Class but the Event ID is there in the primaryKey Entity.

Comment: Di you try `where pe.event.id=?`?

Comment: Didn't work `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@ClassId`, [like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28022644/2387977):

```
 @ClassId(ParticipantPrimaryKey.class)
 class ParticipantEntity { ...
```

Remove from the `ParticipantEntity`:

```
@EmbeddedId
private ParticipantPrimaryKey pKey;
```

And also in the `ParticipantEntity`, add the two keys:

```
@Id
private Long eventId;

@Id
private Long studentId;
```

After that, you can just:

```
SELECT pe FROM ParticipantEntity pe where pe.eventId = :eventId
```