# @OneToMany entity mapping on part of an @embeddedId

Tags: java, spring

I am currently trying to extract a set of entities from a table with a composite key, but I only want to perform the join with id_a to get a set and not both(id_a and id_b) which would yield a single result.

This is not the original code, but it is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
@Entity
public class ItemA {

  @EmbeddedId
  private ItemId itemId;

  @OneToMany
  private Set<ItemB> itemsB = new HashSet<>();

}

@Embeddable
public class ItemID implements Serializable {
  
  private Integer itemIDA;
  private Integer itemIDB;

}

@Entity
public class ItemB {

  @Id
  private Integer itemIDA;

}
```

I have tried a couple of ways, mainly annotating the @OneToMany with @JoinColumn and also with @JoinTable

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "itemB",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "itemIDA") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "itemIDA") }
)
    private Set<ItemB> detalleUsuarios = new HashSet<>();
```

also I tried maybe trying to get inside of the ItemId class

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "itemB",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "itemID.itemIDA") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "itemIDA") }
)
    private Set<ItemB> detalleUsuarios = new HashSet<>();
```

But I get the following error

```
A Foreign key refering com.example.ItemA from com.example.ItemB has the wrong number of column. should be 2
```

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020699/how-to-query-on-subset-of-composite-primary-key

Comment: No, in the link you mentioned, the op wants to query the entity, I am trying to join the tables but only using one part of the composite key